# Authentication in .NET 8 web app allowing 1) Entity Framework / Identity as well as 2) SSO using Microsoft Entra/AAD, and Google - can't do both 1 & 2

Tags: entity-framework, authentication, active-directory, asp.net-identity, .net-8.0

I have a .NET 8 Web Application that I want to allow authentication using Entity Framework / Identity, as well as SSO using Microsoft Entra / Azure Active Directory (AAD), and Google.

I can get all three working, but not at the same time. Either Identity works, and Entra & Google do not; or Identity does not work, and Entra & Google do work.

The problem isn't with the authentication itself, as that always seems to work, it just doesn't remember that it is logged in for the next request. Something going on with cookies and/or the authentication scheme?

Here is the relevant part of `Program.cs`:

```
// Identity (Entity Framework)
// This won't work if Google and Azure below are active
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
    {
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

// This works but breaks Google and Azure
//builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
//    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
//    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
//    .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();

// Authentication (Azure)
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

// Authentication (Google)
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
    {
        googleOptions.ClientId = AppConfig.GetValue("Google:ClientId");
        googleOptions.ClientSecret = AppConfig.GetValue("Google:ClientSecret");
        googleOptions.Events = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthEvents
        {
            OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = context =>
            {
                context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
```

Here are the methods that handle signing in with Entra or Google. Just calling the Challenge method and in the case of Google there is some work to do after I get the response.

```
[HttpGet, HttpPost, ViewPath]
[Route("login/entra")]
public ActionResult LoginEntra()
{
    if (CurrentUser != null)
        return Redirect("/");

    return Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
            OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}

[HttpGet, HttpPost, ViewPath]
[Route("login/google")]
public ActionResult LoginGoogle()
{
    if (CurrentUser != null)
        return Redirect("/");

    return Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/login/google-response", AllowRefresh = true },
            GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}

[HttpGet, HttpPost, ViewPath]
[Route("login/google-response")]
public async Task<IActionResult> LoginGoogleResponse()
{
    string authScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    if (result?.Succeeded == true)
    {
        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(result.Principal.Claims, authScheme, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);
        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
        var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                IsPersistent = true
            };

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(authScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);

        // Redirect to the desired page after login
        return Redirect("/");
    }
    else
    {
        // The user might not be authenticated, handle accordingly
        return Challenge(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
}
```

And finally, this is the API method that is called when the user authenticates with email & password. I am handling the password encryption myself so I also need to verify the login credentials. UserDAO is my custom class that connects to the database to perform user-related functions and stores the "user" object (nothing crazy going on there).

```
[HttpPost, ApiRequest]
[Route("api/Account/Login")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(string email, string password, bool rememberMe = true)
{
    try
    {
        string authScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;

        // Retrieve the user by their email
        ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

        if (user == null)
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Invalid email address or password.");

        // Verify the user's password
        bool isPasswordValid = UserDAO.VerifyPassword(email, password);

        if (!isPasswordValid)
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Invalid email address or password.");

        UserDAO userObj = new UserDAO(email);

        // The password is valid, so sign in the user
        // This bypasses the built-in password check and signs in the user directly
        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, true);

        // bool test = SignInManager.IsSignedIn(???);

        // Set a cookie to remember the email for the form
        if (rememberMe)
            Response.Cookies.Append("User.Email", email);

        // Determine the redirect URL
        string redirect = "/";

        // Return success
        return JsonWebResult.Success(new { Redirect = redirect });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return JsonWebResult.Error(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I tried not specifying the authentication schemes for Entra and Google. Then EF / Identity works but Entra and Google don't work.

I also tried using AddIdentity instead of AddDefaultIdentity. That worked but broke Entra and Google.

Basically everything I've tried that makes Identity work breaks Entra and Google.

Again, the authentication itself always works -- it just doesn't "remember" that the user is signed in. If I sign in with Entra while Identity is working, it will successfully authenticate but `CurrentUser.Identity.IsAuthenticated` will be false on the next request. If I change the code and run it again, making sure Entra is functioning properly (and breaking Identity) it actually shows me as logged into Entra.

Comment: You have the same issue mine. Were you able to figure it out?